# control computeCartesianPath's trajectory.points.size

Tags: ros, cartesian

i set this parameter to 200

```
rosparam set /move_group/ompl/minimum_waypoint_count 200
```

**method1:**

```
move_group_end->plan();
int size = plan.trajectory_.joint_trajectory.points.size();
```

*size is 200*

**method2:**

```
move_group_end->computeCartesianPath( _waypoints, 0.01, 0, recvTraj, true );
int size = recvTraj.joint_trajectory.points.size();
```

*but size is different 200*

If the number of point size is low, the resolution is poor, if the number of point size is high, the resolution is higher.
if i change the eef_step value the resolution changes, but I want size is 200

why method1' results size is 200 but method2's results size is lower then 200

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not required that you call `computeCartesianPath()`. This function linearly interpolates points between the waypoints you pass into it. If the incoming waypoints are already closer together than eef_step, some of them will be dropped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
Actually, I don't run computecartesianpath() after doing plan().
What I want to ask is why there is a size difference between method1 and method2, why is method2 point size less and different from 'minimum_waypoint_count' ?

Comment: method2 is less because the function doesn't look at that parameter; all it knows is the arguments you pass into it. If what you say is accurate, then computeCartesianPath() is dropping input waypoints until the distance is eef_step. I was not aware that it did that. I have updated my answer.